# Mvc RouteUrl with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                 "RouteSample",
               "Controler/Action/{sampleId}",
               new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", sampleId=     UrlParameter.Optional }
);

<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("RouteSample", new { sampleId= 5 })> sample </a>


ActionResult Action(var sampleId)
{
         // Here I always get sampleId as null. I didn't get any value
         // I always get value only by RouteData.Values["Id"].. and another doubt is I have parameter name is sampleId. But I can get data only by mentioning "Id" in RouteData values.. why is like that ?
}
```

I always get value only by RouteData.Values["Id"].. and another doubt is I have parameter name is sampleId. But I can get data only by mentioning "Id" in RouteData values.. why is like that ?

Comment: only the type of parameter which is getting passed on should be same name is never fixed, depends upon the user. :)

Comment: What URL does `@Url.RouteUrl("RouteSample", new { sampleId= 5 }` generates on the client?

Comment: How can you declare sampleId as var?

Comment: Do you have other routes defined? Looks another route is being picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `routes.MapRoute`'s attributes are wrong.
Try This.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{sampleId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", sampleId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: No. By route name only I'm calling the action. It's going correctly. But for me sampleId only cannot be pass. It's always null. I can get data only by  RouteData.Values["Id"]

Comment: I think @SanketS is referring to the fact that controller and action should be between brackets like {controller}. But I think this is something that you just missed in the sample code ..